# Backbone view not rendering correctly on subsequent calls to route handler

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-routing

I'm having a problem with rendering a backbone.js view successfully from a route handler (browser application).

My javascript module is currently setup like this:

```
$(function () { // DOM ready
    myModule.Init();
});

var myModule = (function () {

// Models
    var DonorCorpModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ });

// Collections
    var DonorCorpsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model : DonorCorpModel });

// Views
    var DonorCorpsListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize : function () {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
            this.template = Handlebars.compile($('#pre-sort-actions-template').html())
            this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);
        },
        render : function () {
            $(this.el).html(this.template({}));

            this.collection.each(function (donorCorp) {
                var donorCorpBinView = new DonorCorpBinView({
                    model : donorCorp,
                    list : this.collection
                });

                this.$('.donor-corp-bins').append(donorCorpBinView.render().el);
            });

            return this;
        }
    });

    var DonorCorpBinView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName : 'li',
        className : 'donor-corp-bin',
        initialize : function () {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
            this.model.bind('change', this.render);
            this.template = Handlebars.compile($('#pre-sort-actions-donor-corp-bin-view-template').html());
        },
        render : function () {
            var content = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
            $(this.el).html(content);
            return this;
        }
    })

// Routing
    var App = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes : {
            '' : 'home',
            'pre-sort' : 'preSort'
        },

        initialize : function () {
            // ...
        },

        home : function () {
            // ...
        },

        preSort : function () {
            if (donorCorps.length < 1) {
                donorCorps.url = 'http://my/api/donor-corps';
                donorCorps.fetch();
            }

            var donorCorpsList = new DonorCorpsListView({ collection : donorCorps }).render().el;
            $('#document-action-panel').empty().append(donorCorpsList);

            // ...
        }
    });

// Private members
    var app;
    var donorCorps = new DonorCorpsCollection();

// Public operations
    return {
        Init: function () { return init(); }
    };

// Private operations
    function init () {
        app = new App();
        Backbone.history.start({ root: '/myApp/', pushState: true });
        docr.navigate('/', { trigger: true, replace: true});
    }

}(myModule || {}));
```

Everything runs just fine when I run the app...it navigates to the home view as expected. I have links setup with handlers to navigate to the different routes appropriately, and when I run `app.navigate('pre-sort', { trigger: true, replace: true})` it runs just fine, and renders the expected items in the list as expected.

The problem comes when I try to go *back* to the home view, and then back to the pre-sort view again...the items in the list don't get displayed on the screen as I am expecting them to. I'm just getting the empty `pre-sort-actions-template` rendered with no child views appended to it. I've stepped through the code, and can see that the collection is populated and the items are there...but for some reason, my code isn't rendering them to the view properly, and I can't seem to figure out why or what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?? I'm pretty new to backbone, so I'm sure this code isn't written totally right...constructive feedback is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: You might have a context issue in `DonorCorpsListView.render` with `this.$` coming up blank in the `.each` iterator?

Comment: @rjz could you elaborate on that a little more. It does appear that there is something going wrong in that area, but I'm not exactly sure what. What kind of context issue would I have there? The collection that I'm iterating over *is* populated with data...what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

how is the code rendering it to the view after going back home, then to pre-sort again? could you provide some details on that? duplicate items? empty view?

Also, I like to keep an index of my sub-views when I render them so the parent view can always access them regardless of scope. I found a really nice technique for this here: [Backbone.js Tips : Lessons from the trenches](http://devblog.supportbee.com/2011/07/29/backbone-js-tips-lessons-from-the-trenches/)

A quick overview of the pattern I'm referring to is as follows:

```
var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this._viewPointers = {};
    },
    render: function (item) {
        this._viewPointers[item.cid] = new SubView ({
            model: item
        });
        var template = $(this._viewPointers[item.cid].render().el);
        this.$el.append(template);
    }
});

var SubView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.model.on("change", this.render, this);
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html( _.template($('#templateId').html(), this.model.attributes) );
        return this;
    }
});
```

I realize this answer is rather "broad," but it will be easier to answer with more specifics if I can understand the exact issue with the rendering. Hope its of some help regardless :)

Comment: Yeah, I should've included that information to begin with...too vague..sorry...I will correct that.

Comment: Whats happening is that you are creating a new view each time you are accessing that routing parameter without destroying it prior. Also the view lives in the local scope of that routing function, so there is no good way to destroy it. If your whole application lives in one name-space i.e "var app = {}" and everything else lives under app as parameters, you will always be able to access that exact instance which has already been initialized rather than creating a new view each time. Also the collection you are passing into it is never reset, it is just creating everything new each time.

Comment: and instead of "var donorCorpsList = new DonorCorpsListView({ collection : donorCorps }).render().el;" you could do "app.donorCorpsList.reset(donorCorps);" which would trigger your reset, and update the view rather than re-initializing it. Initialize the app.donorCorpsList the first time it is needed, if its there already, just update it :) - Hope this helps!

Comment: lastly - to preserve scope in your view initialization: "this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);" should be "this.collection.bind('reset', this.render, this);" - if not "this" inside "this.render" refers to the collection, not the view.

Comment: Amen to `reset`/no re-create!

Comment: Well, I thought I had it figured out with your suggestions, but Backbone.View doesn't have a reset method, so that's not helping. Also, I was trying to avoid resetting the collection, as in the context of this app, it will be read only, so it won't get changed, so resetting it didn't seem appropriate, especially considering that a reset with no arguments just empties the collection. Sooo...I'm still not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: [Backbone .reset documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset) The reset is to be used on collections, not the view. You can listen for the Reset event within the view in the initialize section. `this.collection.on('reset', this.doThis, this);` and rebuild the view accordingly. OR you can use the backbone router to hide/show views and just get around the problem all together. Reset is the preferred option.